# Linux script to check settings and recommend tuning changes?

Tags: linux, performance-tuning, tuning

I'm searching for a script to run on our linux server and recommend various tuning changes we might consider making, as well as their suggested values for consideration. Any ideas if something like this exists?

The server runs a Wordpress site and we'll be working on implementing caching, but based on the VPS instance's available resources, we were hoping there was a script we could run to recommend best guesses of values to tweak for Apache, PHP and MySQL to get the best level of performance out of the size of VPS we happen to be on.

The idea was resize for a promotion and run it again, then downsize, run yet again to get new best values. Max clients, memory allocation, etc.

Comment: Not sure how it's "vague". I told the community precisely what I am hosting. It's a Wordpress site. I also included exactly which types of values I was attempting to change.

Comment: First, most systems come with reasonable defaults already. There are no scripts to tune for the general cause since the systems are usually setup by default to handle the general usage.  You have mentioned a package, and that you are expecting an above-average peak soon, but that really tells us nothing.  Tuning for performance requires an extremely in-depth understanding of your system.  You haven't given nearly enough information.  In reality a lot of tuning is done by trial and error.  Produce a lot of traffic, and then see what breaks.  Fix what was broke, and then repeat.

Answer (score 2):

Tuning in this respect depends on the applications' needs.  These needs vary from application to application.  However, in general, the application vendor usually provides required configurations and usually includes some tuning ideas that could be explored.

Thus something as general as you want probably does not really exist.